# Convert array of objects into an array of one object

Tags: javascript

Given this data format:

```
data = {
    id_1: [
      { name: "John", key_1: "data 1", key_2: null, key_3: null },
      { name: "John", key_1: null, key_2: "data 2", key_3: null },
      { name: "John", key_1: null, key_2: null, key_3: "data 3" },
    ],
    id_2: [
      { name: "Mary", key_1: "data 1", key_2: null, key_3: null },
      { name: "Mary", key_1: null, key_2: "data 2", key_3: null },
      { name: "Mary", key_1: null, key_2: null, key_3: "data 3" },
    ],
    id_3: [
      { name: "Bob", key_1: "data 1", key_2: null, key_3: null },
      { name: "Bob", key_1: null, key_2: "data 2", key_3: null },
      { name: "Bob", key_1: null, key_2: null, key_3: "data 3" },
    ],
  }
```

I'd like to convert it to this data format:

```
data = {
    id_1: [
      { name: "John", key_1: "data 1", key_2: "data 2", key_3: "data 3" }
    ],
    id_2: [
      { name: "Mary", key_1: "data 1", key_2: "data 2", key_3: "data 3" }
    ],
    id_3: [
      { name: "Bob", key_1: "data 1", key_2: "data 2", key_3: "data 3" }
    ],
  }
```

Inside the object, there will always only be one key (key_1/key_2/key_3) that has a value and the other 2 will always be null. It will also always contain a key of name with the same value.

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't write code on demand but it can help if you've written code and can't get it to work. Also, given that you're collapsing each array to a single entry, why continue to have arrays in the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const reduce = (obj) => {

  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((outerAcc,[key, value]) => {

    outerAcc[key] = value.reduce((subAcc, subItem) => {
      Object.entries(subItem).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        subAcc[key] = subAcc[key] || value;
      })
      return subAcc;
    }, {})

    return outerAcc;

  }, {})

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Focusing on the title, if you want to reduce an array to something else, you can consider Array.prototype.reduce() (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Since you need to do this reduction for all of your object keys, you can consider Object.keys() (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Based on this you should be able to figure out one possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```js
const data = {
  id_1: [
    { name: "John", key_1: "data 1", key_2: null, key_3: null },
    { name: "John", key_1: null, key_2: "data 2", key_3: null },
    { name: "John", key_1: null, key_2: null, key_3: "data 3" },
  ],
  id_2: [
    { name: "Mary", key_1: "data 1", key_2: null, key_3: null },
    { name: "Mary", key_1: null, key_2: "data 2", key_3: null },
    { name: "Mary", key_1: null, key_2: null, key_3: "data 3" },
  ],
  id_3: [
    { name: "Bob", key_1: "data 1", key_2: null, key_3: null },
    { name: "Bob", key_1: null, key_2: "data 2", key_3: null },
    { name: "Bob", key_1: null, key_2: null, key_3: "data 3" },
  ],
}

function convert(data) {
  return Object.values(data).forEach( // iterate over values of data object
    arr => {                          
      arr.forEach(                    // iterate over items in arrays for each id_N      
        item => {
          Object.entries(item).forEach(([key, value]) => {
            if (value !== null) {
              arr[0][key] = value; // collect all non-null values in first item
            }
          })
        }
      )
      arr.length = 1;
    }
  )
}

convert(data); // convert data in-place

console.log(data);
```

Useful links:

- [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
- [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)
- [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)